# SQL Select employees with work history in multiple states

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, self-join

I need a query that will show only employees who have been paid in more than one state.

The query will pull three columns:

1. EmployeeID
2. WorkLocation
3. LastPayDate

My current, unsuccessful attempt:

```
Select EmployeeID
    , WorkLocation
    , max(LastPayDate)
from Table 
group by EmployeeID, WorkLocation
having COUNT(distinct WorkLocation) > 1
```

This query pulls zero records. I know there are employees who have worked in multiple states, however. I am not sure where my logic breaks down.

Any instruction is much appreciated.

Comment: The query posted should return 0 not all

Comment: `having COUNT(distinct EmployeeID) > 1` should return 0 rows not all rows as each row is grouped by `EmployeeID WorkLocation` and will just have a single value.

Comment: Can you comment on the edited post @MartinSmith?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a count(workLocation) > 1 which indicates that they have worked in more than 1 state. Specify this in the HAVING clause. Since you're only concerned in GROUPS which contain multiple WorkLocations.

If you're trying to check for multiple work locations within a specific year, you will perform that logic in the WHERE clause.

```
select EmployeeId
from table xyz
//where year(LastPayDate) == 2015
group by EmployeeId 
having count(distinct WorkLocation) > 1
```

Comment: This will currently return all `EmployeeId` that have more than one row - for any  (not null) `WorkLocation` - not necessarily different ones.

Comment: Change to `having count(distinct WorkLocation) > 1`, this should work as expected

Comment: This is good. How would one also include WorkLocation and LastPayDate in the record? @JustinDanielson

Comment: When using a group by, you can only include columns if you're using aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to use a subquery. Solution as follows:

```
Select t.EmployeeID
     , t.WorkLocation
     , t.LastPayDate
From Table t
Where t.EmployeeID in
    (
     Select t2.EmployeeID
     From Table t2
     Group by t2.EmployeeID
     Having count(distinct t2.WorkLocation) > 1
    )
Group by t.EmployeeID, t.WorkLocation
Order by t.EmployeeID
```

Thanks to everyone for helping.